# Is there a way to debug AWS SNS messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm sending, to a AWS SNS topic,  through my application, some messages.

Is there a way to  debug if these messages are actually reaching SNS, without attaching any subscription?

My actual "way" to debug is  subscribing a SQS queue to catch all messages and  see if there's traffic on this SQS destination queue.
(setting this up  was not  also straight forward since after successful subscription  of the  SQS, I've found out that I had also to edit Access policies on SQS to allow SNS to reach out the queue other wise no feedback about SNS sending anything)

Adding the following on Access policies Statement JSON prop:

```
{
    "Sid": "topic-subscription-arn:aws:sns:xx-xx-1:9999999999999:my-sns-notifier-topic",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal":
    {
        "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:xx-xx-1:9999999999999:my-sqs-queue-catcher",
    "Condition":
    {
        "ArnLike":
        {
            "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:xx-xx-1:9999999999999:my-sns-notifier-topic"
        }
    }
}
```

Any better idea?

Comment: What are you actually trying to validate? Is the question whether your application is sending the messages that it's supposed to, or is it that SNS doesn't work as advertised?

Comment: "Is there a way to debug if these messages are actually reaching SNS, without attaching any subscription?" If I publish a message to a SNS topic see if the request got there without the need to have a subscriber set to see it.

Comment: Well, you could always retrieve the `NumberOfMessagesPublished` CloudWatch metric, but that seems like an ugly hack compared to attaching an SQS subscription.

Comment: But it sounds like you're trying to validate whether SNS works as advertised, and that seems rather pointless.

Comment: If you're interested in whether the Publish API for SNS is being called, then CloudTrail might be your go to.  If the source is another AWS service, you can provide that as the Event Source. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html

Answer (score 0):

If by "debug" then you mean read, then it is not possible to do this without attaching a subscription to your topic. If a message arrives for a topic that does not have any subscriptions, it will simply be thrown away by SNS as there is no where to deliver it.